# I want to auto-install SharePoint 2013, 2016 and 2019 without having internet connection, is this possible?

Tags: administration, 2019, installation, configuration, autospinstaller

We want to migrate a lot of SharePoint 2010 environments to 2019. And to do so we need to arrange for 3 environments;SharePoint 2013, 2016 and 2019.

So to fasten this process can we write a power shell script which we can run on each server and it will install the SharePoint 2013, 2016 and 2019 on 3 different servers? So we can define a configuration file where we define the service accounts to be used for the installation + the database server name, then run this power shell script inside each server without having to manually monitor and response to the installation process. is this possible?

So in other words we run the Power-Shell script and we can leave the process to install the SharePoint based on the configuration file we will be providing on each environment/server. So is this possible? and how?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a common scenario for migration process in Enterprise infra without internet connection. For this task and quick install Ana configure SP environment quickly you can use AutoSPInstaller: https://autospinstaller.com/
Please see guide. Shortly You prepare a configuration on WebUI=> copy and save Config to a file of each you enviroments=> Prepare install and configuration package=> Run.